# Need to build a xamarin.forms app but i need users to interact with each other for example if user1 changes a chunk of data it changes for user2 too

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, xamarin.forms

I need to know what kind of database can i use for users to interact with each other. For example if i needed to build a forum inside the app the users need to see each others questions and so far and i don't think a local db like sqlite works for this.

Comment: What is your question here, and specifically, what does it have to do with programming? It *looks* like you're asking for a recommendation, which is off topic for Stack Overflow, as are asking for the opinions of others.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Central Database on a server, based on which server will notify your client apps about the data update and it can show the updated version on each devices. A local db doesn't work for your requirement. Based on your requirement, you can look into RDBMS or No SQL Dbs. Or you can even look into Redis like DBs.

Comment: Realm would be also one option to go.
You can create your server e.g. on Linux machine and register it in your app.
Actually, it is really well explained what can be done with Realm in Xamarin in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4A93-qmqyA&t=21s